# Rolling dice in list

Tags: python, list

Here's how I want the example to look like.

```
Enter # of dice [3,6]: 4
You have rolled: [9, 3, 8, 8]
```

The code

```
def dice():

    n = input( "Enter # of dice [3,6]: " )

    n = int( n )

    diceList = []
    for row in range( 0, n + 1 ):

        rowList = []
        for col in range( 0, n + 1 ):
            rowList.append( row * col )
        diceList.append( rowList )

    print( "\nYou have rolled: ", diceList )
dice()
```

You can see how it keeps adding lists with each number you put in between 3 and 6, and I am not sure how to fix that. I also feel I should put in random.randint to get random numbers like the example shown above.

Comment: what do you want it to do exactly? roll the dice 4 times and print the results?

Comment: Maybe you want something like this? `diceList = [random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(n)]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, yes or any number I put in, say ```[3,6]``` I put in 4, and it shows 4 random numbers for the dice as result; so if I put in 6, it will show 6 random numbers for the dice. In this case, if you output the code, and you type in 4, it shows 4 lists which I do not want. I would like to show only one list, as shown in the example.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `rowList`?

Comment: @alec, I tried that but it gave me an error.

Comment: There should be no error unless you didn't import random.

Comment: @alec, you just answered my question. Thanks a lot man!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me what the purpose of `rowList` would be in your code, but that and the extra `for` is the cause of the extra lists.
Also, you never generate a random number there.
To do so, Python offers you the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.

The code below, would work as you expect:

```
import random


def dice():
    n = input( "Enter # of dice [3,6]: " )
    n = int( n )
    diceList = []
    for row in range(0, n):
        diceList.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    print( "\nYou have rolled: ", diceList)


dice()
```

or, a bit more concisely:

```
import random


def dice():
    n = input( "Enter # of dice [3,6]: " )
    n = int( n )
    diceList = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(0, n)]
    print( "\nYou have rolled: ", diceList)


dice()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I appreciate the help!